# How to find out latest date from two different date columns in R and create new variable?

Tags: r

I have a data like:

```
cu ID   date1         date2  

1       2019-11-04    2018-11-06
2       2019-10-27    2018-10-30
3       2019-09-25    2018-09-26
4        blank        2018-09-26
5       2018-09-26    2018-09-20
6       2017-09-10    2018-09-20
```

I need to create a variable called latest date (comparing date1 and date2) with the recent date (like below)

```
cu ID   date1         date2         **Latest date**

1       2019-11-04    2018-11-06    2018-11-06
2       2019-10-27    2018-10-30    2018-10-30
3       2019-09-25    2018-09-26    2018-09-26
4        blank        2018-09-26    2018-09-26
5       2018-09-26    2018-09-20    2018-09-26
6       2017-09-10    2018-09-20    2018-09-20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we must convert the dates into `Date` objects in R

```
df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date1)
df$date2 <- as.Date(df$date2)
```

**Method 1**
Then we can `apply` a rowise (`1`) `max` function while ignoring NA's (blanks) with `na.rm = T`

```
df$latest_date <- apply(df[c("date1","date2")],1, max, na.rm=T)
```

**Method 2**
another method is using `pmax` function to get the same results

```
df$latest_date <- pmax(df$date1,df$date2, na.rm=T)
```

**output:**

```
> df
  cu_ID      date1      date2 latest_date
1     1 2019-11-04 2018-11-06  2019-11-04
2     2 2019-10-27 2018-10-30  2019-10-27
3     3 2019-09-25 2018-09-26  2019-09-25
4     4       <NA> 2018-09-26  2018-09-26
5     5 2018-09-26 2018-09-20  2018-09-26
6     6 2017-09-10 2018-09-20  2018-09-20
```